# WCF configuration

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, wcf

I have the following reference to my service  in my App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Statistics" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://Statistics-test.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Statistics"
    contract="am.Statistics"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_Statistics" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So I was wondering what is the difference in consuming the service like the following two options.

Option 1:

this option will take as default the endpoint address that I have in the App.config "http://Statistics-test.svc"

```
 using (StatisticsClient client = new  StatisticsClient())
        {
           var res = client.GetWhatever();
        }
```

Option 2:
  Here would like to provide the URL for the service to point to  Production (both are the same), so I will provide the "endpointConfigurationName" and the "remote address" = "http://Statistics-prod.svc"

```
    string Url = "http://Statistics-prod.svc";

    using (StatisticsClient client = new StatisticsClient(BasicHttpBinding_Statistics,Url))
        {
           var res = client.GetWhatever();
        }
```

I would like to know if there is any performance or any other issue in passing the parameters to the WCF in the Option 2. Good to mention that both ways work fine but the second option is just simpler since I can just change the URL dynamically as needed.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach allows you to change the endpoint without the need to rebuild the application. But the rest is performing the same way